# Html event listener not added properly

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I added onclick listener in html file but firefox dev tool displays event listener as blank.

```
<button onclick='onDelete(this)' type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>delete</button>
```

function `onDelete()` is defined in external javascript file named `script.js`

```
function onDelete(element){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
    var id = element.parentElement.parentElement.id;
    request.open('GET', 'delete.php?' + 'id='+ id , true);
    request.send();
}
```

JS file is included inside heade tag.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/custom/js/script.js'></script>
```

It seems that `script.js` has been loaded successfully...
How can I fix this?

Comment: `var id = element.parentElement.parentElement.id;` <-- could it be that?

Comment: Is it ok in other browser?

Comment: Style note: Requests which change the state of a system should never use the HTTP GET method. Instead, for your use case, use DELETE or at the very least, POST.